# I cannot make safe_to_exit method in npyscreen work

Tags: python, npyscreen

I think I missing something very basic but I cannot make this function work.
I am running python 3.6.12 on Redhat with npyscreen 4.10.5.  My expectation is that the safe_to_exit function could be used to validate any input immediately when the user exits the field (using the tab key) but I cannot make it fire at all.  Possibly I have misunderstood this completely.  Here is my test code, cut down to make it as simple as possible:

```
import npyscreen

def test1(*args):
    F = npyscreen.Form(name='My Test Application')
    Field1 = F.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="My Test Field")
    Field1.safe_to_exit = Field1_Validations
    F.edit()
    return Field1.value

def Field1_Validations():
    npyscreen.notify_confirm("Safe to exit")
    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    onefield = npyscreen.wrapper_basic(test1)
    print("Results are : {} ".format(onefield))
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hair pulling I worked it out.  They syntax is (applying to the code sample above):

```
self.Field1.entry_widget.safe_to_exit = Field1_Validations
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm still digging, but I have discovered that it appears safe_to_exit is not implemented on all widgets.  Changing the widget from "TitleText" to "Textfield" resulted in the validations code firing.